# Asynchronous Reset in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Recently I got stuck between two always block statements while implementing asynchronous reset.

One statement is :

```
always @(posedge clk or posedge reset)
```

The second statement is :

```
always @(posedge clk or reset)
```

I tried to find the difference between these two statements. Both statements target asynchronous reset, the first statement with edge sensitive reset and another statement with level reset. Please help me to find other differences which will affect the functioning of always block.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have not tried to synthesize that code.

The first form only works if you add a following:

```
if (reset)
 ...
```

Which gives a high active asynchronous reset.

The second form can not be synthesized at all.

> Please help me to find other differences which will affect the functioning of always block.

That is rather a big question. You can't expect us to take you through all possible always constructs.